# Lost Social Connection Icons after uploading custom images

Tags: commerce, theming, media

I created a subtheme for Commerce Kickstart / Omega. As part of the refresh, I want to use the existing "Connect with Us" block, but replace the existing icons with customized images (theme consistent colors).

I uploaded replacement files to `sites/all/SUBTHEME/images`, using the same file name and type as in the original theme:

- icon_facebook.png
- icon_twitter.png

Saved / refreshed: Icons disappeared from the block. If I was uploading to the wrong directory, I feel like it would continue to show the original yellow icons, but the icons no longer show at all.

Here's the code from the css file:

```
  #block-menu-menu-social-connection .content ul.menu li span,
  #block-menu-menu-social-connection .content ul.menu li a {
    color: #eeeeee; }
  #block-menu-menu-social-connection .content ul.menu li a.facebook {
    background: url("../images/icon_facebook.png") 2% 50% no-repeat;
    /* LTR */ }
  #block-menu-menu-social-connection .content ul.menu li a.twitter {
    background: url("../images/icon_twitter.png") 2% 50% no-repeat;
    /* LTR */ }
  #block-menu-menu-social-connection .content ul.menu li a.instagram {
    background: url("../images/icon_instagram.png") 2% 50% no-repeat;
    /* LTR */ }
```

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: I did clear cache, but no dice.

Comment: have you tried going to `yourwebsite.com/sites/all/themes/SUBTHEME/images/icon_facebook.png` to see if its working

Comment: check your recent log messages in `yourwebsite.com/admin/reports/dblog`

Comment: go to where the icons are suppose to be and inspect the element with your browser to see where the url is pointing to.

Comment: @NoSssweat - I tried inspect element. The path is correct, but the file looks empty. It's a checkboard, like a transparent background in PSD. When I open the PNG in Photoshop though, I see the image. Puzzling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After troubleshooting with @nosssweat, it turns out this is an issue with Adobe PS saving empty PNG files. Surprise!

To fix, I switched to 24-bit PNG and was able to save the web-optimized format correctly. All issues fixed here.